# ejtserver won't start, but no errors, after power outage

Tags: install4j

I have an install4j license that is served by ejtserver.  After a power outage ejtserver doesn't start any more.  It doesn't issue any errors, either.

My workaround is to run ejtserver_console.  That starts up and opens the port to listen for connections.

I appear to be running ejtserver 1.12.  What can I do to get my ejtserver running as expected?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, please check the service manager if the "ej-technologies license server" service is started and if not, please start it while ejtserver_console is closed. Executing `ejtserver` directly has no effect. The log file is located in `log/server.log`, an error log would be in `log/error.log` only if an error has occurred. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to share a log file or error log.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention I'm on Linux.  There is no error.log in the log directory.  Log messages only show up the running ejtserver_console, not when running ejtserver.